# Using Azure Storage SDK with Django (and removing dependency on django-storages entirely)

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-storage

Does anyone have any tips on using [azure-storage](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) directly with Django? I ask because currently I'm trying to set up Azure Cloud Storage for my Django app (hosted on Azure VM with Ubuntu OS), and `django-storages` doesn't seem to be interfacing with Azure Storage SDK correctly (known issue: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151766/using-azure-as-a-storage-backend-for-django-using-django-storages)). The fix listed there won't work for me given my Django version is < 1.6.2.

Thus I'll need to use Azure-storage directly with Django. Has anyone set that up before? I need to save **images** and **mp3s** on the Cloud Storage.

---

Currently, in my models.py, I have:

```
def upload_to_location(instance, filename):
    try:
        blocks = filename.split('.') 
        ext = blocks[-1]
        filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
        instance.title = blocks[0]
        return os.path.join('uploads/', filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))
        return 0

class Photo(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_location, null=True, blank=True )
```

And then `django-storages` and `boto` take care of the rest. However, when I hook django-storages up with Azure Cloud Storage, I get the following error:

```
Exception Value:      
'module' object has no attribute 'WindowsAzureMissingResourceError'

Exception Location:     
/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/azure_storage.py in exists, line 46
```

And the relevant snippet of the code is:

```
def exists(self, name):
    try:
        self.connection.get_blob_properties(
            self.azure_container, name)
    except azure.WindowsAzureMissingResourceError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Seems that the connection to the Azure container is failing. In my settings.py, I have:

```
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'
    AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'photodatabasestorage'
    AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'something'
    AZURE_CONTAINER = 'somecontainer'
```

As described earlier, I need a solution that bypasses django-storages entirely, and just relies on Azure Storage SDK to get the job done.

*Note: ask me for more information in case you need it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly use [Azure-Storage python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python) in the Django apps just like using the sdk in common python applications. You can refer to [official guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/) for getting started.

Here is the test code snippet in the Django app:

```
def putfiles(request):
blob_service = BlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)
PROJECT_ROOT = path.dirname(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)))
try:
    blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(
            'mycontainer',
            '123.jpg',
            path.join(path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'uploads'),'123.jpg'),
            x_ms_blob_content_type='image/jpg'
    )
    result = True
except:
    print(sys.exc_info()[1])
    result = False
return HttpResponse(result)


def listfiles(request):
    blob_service = BlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)
    blobs = []
    result = []
    marker = None
    while True:
        batch = blob_service.list_blobs('mycontainer', marker=marker)
        blobs.extend(batch)
        if not batch.next_marker:
            break
        marker = batch.next_marker
    for blob in blobs:
        result.extend([{'name':blob.name}])
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result))
```

Comment: Can you quickly clarify what `PROJECT_ROOT` is?

Comment: It‘s the abs path of your application in OS

Comment: Hmm, so I'll somehow need to override `upload_to` in my ImageField attribute with `blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path` (or `put_block_blob_from_file`)?

Comment: Moved the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293603/how-to-use-azures-blobservice-object-to-upload-a-file-associated-to-a-django-mo